# React Error Handling Fetch Data Venues List

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, conditional-statements, foursquare

I am fetching data using the Foursquare API within a React app using the Google Map API and react-google-map.

When I create a list of venues and try to check if the error handling works by deleting some characters from the API link, the app crashes because the venues state is empty.

I should be adding a conditional statement to the function that maps through the data to check if it's null, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my repository:

```
https://github.com/Katesold/Watford-Map
```

If someone could advise me on how to do it, I would really appreciate it.

What I have been trying looks like this:

```
filterCafes = (cafes, query) => {
    cafes !== undefined ? cafes.filter(cafe => 
    cafe.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())): "error";
}
```

Here's the error I got:
[app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwPZ4.jpg)

Comment: It would be great if you could attach the error you're getting. Off the top of my head, one potential problem with the code snippet you attached would be that filterCafes isn't actually returning any value. Removing the curly braces or adding a return statement might help. Otherwise, you'll get an error trying to call `map` on the result of filterCafes, which is undefined.

Comment: @Tomty I have added the image of the error, sorry I did not upload it first. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your problems can be alleviated by ensuring that cafes is set to null by default. Then in `Sidebar1.js`, I have added a truthy check to your filter that you used in the render method (`cafePlaces && cafePlaces.filter...`). This means that the filter will only be executed if cafePlaces was successfully fetched in your parent component, where you fetch the data.

You will also need to update `Places.js`, as you use cafes in there too. I have also added an early return to the `filterCafes` method as it will error out when you try filtering as not cafes were loaded into the parent state if the API called failed.

*(P.S. Please note I broke your API call on purpose in the example code provided below).*

## App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Map from "./Map";
import SideBar from "./SideBar1.js";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import Footer from "./Footer.js";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    cafes: null,
    clickedCafe: {},
    filteredCafe: []
  };

  // get the data for the cafes in Watford and catch any errors from Foursquare and Map
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=51.656489,-.39032&intent=browse&radius=10000&client_id=XQSXUGIR140AWUVFJJ120S31IPIXQYIO2QJ2ZN2U0ZPLLG4P&client_secret=A0N5P5VI4NG5UQK2GV2M0WU1FYY3KZ0EUYV0YMYZSX5IHHSU&v=26"
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          cafes: data.response.venues,
          filteredCafe: data.response.venues
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(
          "An error occurred while trying to fetch data from Foursquare: " +
            error
        );
      });

    window.gm_authFailure = () => {
      alert("An error occurred while trying to load Google Map");
    };
  }

  // Update filtered list of venues
  updateList = filteredCafe => {
    this.setState({ filteredCafe });
  };

  // Show the infowindow when a place is clicked
  handleInfoWindow = clickedCafe => {
    this.setState({ clickedPlace: clickedCafe });
    this.setState({ menuHidden: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app" role="application" aria-label="map">
        <Header />
        <Map
          cafes={this.state.filteredCafe}
          clickedPlace={this.state.clickedPlace}
          handleInfoWindow={this.handleInfoWindow}
        />

        <SideBar
          cafes={this.state.cafes}
          handleInfoWindow={this.handleInfoWindow}
          updateList={this.updateList}
          menuHidden={this.state.menuHidden}
        />

        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Sidebar1.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SideBar extends Component {
  state = {
    query: ""
  };

  //filter the cafes depending on the search
  refreshQuery = query => {
    this.setState({ query });
    this.props.updateList(this.filterCafes(this.props.cafes, query));
  };

  filterCafes = (cafes, query) => {
    if (!cafes) {
      return;
    }
    cafes.filter(cafe => cafe.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
  };

  //cafes displayed in SideBar
  render() {
    const cafePlaces = this.props.cafes;
    const typedQuery = this.state.query;

    const listCafes =
      cafePlaces &&
      this.filterCafes(cafePlaces, typedQuery).map((cafe, idx) => {
        return (
          <li
            key={cafe.id}
            className="cafe"
            tabIndex={0}
            aria-label={cafe.name}
            onClick={() => {
              this.props.handleInfoWindow(idx);
            }}
            onKeyPress={() => {
              this.props.handleInfoWindow(idx);
            }}
          >
            {cafe.name}
          </li>
        );
      });

    return (
      <aside>
        <div className="sideBar">
          <div className="locations-list">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for a place"
              aria-label="Type to look for a cafe"
              value={this.state.query}
              onChange={e => this.refreshQuery(e.target.value)}
            />
            <ul aria-labelledby="Cafe list">{listCafes}</ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
    );
  }
}

export default SideBar;
```

## Places.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";

class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    const places = this.props.cafes;
    const animatePlace = this.props.clickedPlace;

    /* create Google Map App and markers, infowindow from FourSquare API from https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/docs/configuration.md 
and https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#infowindow and https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/753 */

    const style = {
      height: "100%"
    };

    const styleMap = {
      height: "600px",
      width: "100%"
    };

    //define map with markers and infowindow then return it below to display within container div
    const WMap = withScriptjs(
      withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
          defaultZoom={14}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.656489, lng: -0.39032 }}
        >
          {places &&
            places.map((place, i) => (
              <Marker
                key={i}
                position={{ lat: place.location.lat, lng: place.location.lng }}
                id={place.id}
                name={place.name}
                onClick={() => {
                  this.props.handleInfoWindow(i);
                }}
                animation={
                  animatePlace === i ? window.google.maps.Animation.DROP : null
                }
              >
                {animatePlace === i && (
                  <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                    <div
                      className="infoWindow"
                      tabIndex={0}
                      aria-label="Infowindow"
                    >
                      <h2>{place.name}</h2>
                      <hr />

                      <p>
                        <strong>Address: </strong>
                        {place.location.formattedAddress[0]}
                      </p>
                      <p>{place.location.formattedAddress[1]}</p>
                      <p>{place.location.formattedAddress[2]}</p>
                      <p>{place.location.formattedAddress[3]}</p>
                      <p>{place.location.formattedAddress[4]}</p>
                    </div>
                  </InfoWindow>
                )}
              </Marker>
            ))}
        </GoogleMap>
      ))
    );

    return (
      <div className="map">
        <div className="wmap" role="application">
          <WMap
            googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFk8F7SikfJihxgfeWargVEIsb31hwlwA&v=3.exp"
            loadingElement={<div style={style} />}
            containerElement={<div style={styleMap} />}
            mapElement={<div style={style} />}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Thank you @Win , great advice :)